# Login form in layout YII

Tags: php, forms, yii

Yii noob here.

I made a dropdown login form which is rendered as a partial. It works fine when user credentials are correct and redirects wherever I want to. However if form validation or authentication fails, I can't get the error messages to be passed to the login form. I think the problem is that my login form is in the main layout (because I want it accessible at any moment) and that the controller can not pass in a clean way variables to the layout.

So here is my login action in SiteController

```
public function actionLogin ()
        {                       
                $form = new LoginForm;
                if (isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
                {
                        $form->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];

                        //validate user input and redirect to user panel if valid
                        if($form->validate() && $form ->login())
                        {
                                $success = "oui";
                                $this->render('user_panel');    
                        } 
                        else
                        {                                               
                                $success = $form->getError('login').$form->getError('password');                                                        
                                $this->render('index',array('success'=>$success));
                                //here I can pass the error messages to the index view for example, but not to the login form in the main layout, how can I do this?
                        }                                                                                                       
                }                       
        }
```

Also, in the login form, i set enableAjaxValidation to true, how does that work? Can I say to the controller to respond also via Ajax directly to the form?

One last question : the form should echo $form->errorSummary($model) &model being new LoginForm. Why doesn't it ever display an error summary?

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$success = $form->getError('login').$form->getError('password');                                                        
$this->render('index',array('success'=>$success));
```

Should be:

```
$this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
```

The form should have several lines like

```
<?php echo $form->error($model,'field'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

These lines will receive the errors from the validator and display them, so you don't need to pass anything when there is an error.

Lastly, for best practice, your naming convention leads to errors in analysis, your variable for errors is actually called $success.

Comment: Like I said in the beggining the login form is in the layout, so passing errors doesn't seem to work this way. Actually instead of rendering 'index' I should rende whatever view the user logged in from.